# try to run kibana (elasticsearch) version 7.9.3

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I try to setup elasticsearch plus kibana. I use version 7.9.3 for both. I have no problem with elasticsearch, but get problems with kibana start.

Before launching kibana, I run
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_task_manager_1
and
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_1

The when I run -> kibana, I get the following logs

```
  log   [14:11:50.828] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: beats_management
  log   [14:11:50.846] [warning][plugins-discovery] Expect plugin "id" in camelCase, but found: > triggers_actions_ui
  log   [14:12:12.364] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "visTypeXy" is disabled.
  log   [14:12:12.365] [info][plugins-service] Plugin "auditTrail" is disabled.
  log   [14:12:12.932] [warning][config][deprecation] Environment variable "DATA_PATH" will be removed.  It has been replaced with kibana.yml setting "path.data"
  log   [14:12:12.933] [warning][config][deprecation] Setting [elasticsearch.username] to "elastic" is deprecated. You should use the "kibana_system" user instead.
  log   [14:12:12.933] [warning][config][deprecation] kibana.defaultAppId is deprecated and will be removed in 8.0. Please use the `defaultRoute` advanced setting instead
  log   [14:12:12.934] [warning][config][deprecation] Config key [monitoring.cluster_alerts.email_notifications.email_address] will be required for email notifications to work in 8.0."
  log   [14:12:12.934] [warning][config][deprecation] Setting [monitoring.username] to "elastic" is deprecated. You should use the "kibana_system" user instead.
  log   [14:12:13.068] [info][plugins-system] Setting up [92] plugins: [taskManager,licensing,observability,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,code,usageCollection,ossTelemetry,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetry,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,newsfeed,mapsLegacy,kibanaLegacy,translations,timelion,share,legacyExport,charts,esUiShared,bfetch,expressions,data,home,cloud,console,consoleExtensions,apmOss,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,upgradeAssistant,licenseManagement,watcher,indexPatternManagement,advancedSettings,fileUpload,dataEnhanced,savedObjects,visualizations,visualize,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,visTypeTimelion,features,security,snapshotRestore,reporting,enterpriseSearch,encryptedSavedObjects,ingestManager,indexManagement,rollup,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,beats_management,transform,ingestPipelines,maps,graph,canvas,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypeMetric,visTypeMarkdown,tileMap,regionMap,inputControlVis,discover,discoverEnhanced,dashboard,lens,dashboardMode,savedObjectsManagement,spaces,lists,eventLog,actions,case,alerts,alertingBuiltins,ml,securitySolution,infra,monitoring,logstash,apm,uptime]
  log   [14:12:13.418] [warning][config][plugins][security] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [14:12:13.419] [warning][config][plugins][security] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
  log   [14:12:13.485] [warning][config][plugins][reporting] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [14:12:13.488] [info][config][plugins][reporting] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, and is supported for Darwin OS. Automatically enabling Chromium sandbox.
  log   [14:12:13.492] [warning][config][encryptedSavedObjects][plugins] Generating a random key for xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey. To be able to decrypt encrypted saved objects attributes after restart, please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml
  log   [14:12:13.499] [warning][ingestManager][plugins] Fleet APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml.
  log   [14:12:13.617] [warning][actions][actions][plugins] APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml.
  log   [14:12:13.645] [warning][alerting][alerts][plugins][plugins] APIs are disabled due to the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin using an ephemeral encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in kibana.yml.
  log   [14:12:13.847] [info][monitoring][monitoring][plugins] config sourced from: production cluster
  log   [14:12:14.337] [info][savedobjects-service] Waiting until all Elasticsearch nodes are compatible with Kibana before starting saved objects migrations...
  log   [14:12:14.405] [info][savedobjects-service] Starting saved objects migrations
  log   [14:12:14.434] [info][savedobjects-service] Creating index .kibana_1.
  log   [14:12:14.438] [info][savedobjects-service] Creating index .kibana_task_manager_1.
  log   [14:12:44.442] [warning][savedobjects-service] Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
  log   [14:12:46.956] [warning][savedobjects-service] Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [resource_already_exists_exception] index [.kibana_task_manager_1/jk0bviqYTSe3rjxfIVSrUg] already exists, with { index_uuid="jk0bviqYTSe3rjxfIVSrUg" & index=".kibana_task_manager_1" }
  log   [14:12:46.958] [warning][savedobjects-service] Another Kibana instance appears to be migrating the index. Waiting for that migration to complete. If no other Kibana instance is attempting migrations, you can get past this message by deleting index .kibana_task_manager_1 and restarting Kibana.
  log   [14:12:46.962] [warning][savedobjects-service] Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [resource_already_exists_exception] index [.kibana_1/tjLySaoISgaPcEviglY2Ww] already exists, with { index_uuid="tjLySaoISgaPcEviglY2Ww" & index=".kibana_1" }
  log   [14:12:46.962] [warning][savedobjects-service] Another Kibana instance appears to be migrating the index. Waiting for that migration to complete. If no other Kibana instance is attempting migrations, you can get past this message by deleting index .kibana_1 and restarting Kibana.
```

Here is my kibana configuration file

```
path.data: /usr/local/var/lib/kibana/data
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "localhost"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
server.rewriteBasePath: false

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
server.name: "kibana"

# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://localhost:9200"]

# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
kibana.defaultAppId: "dashboards"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
elasticsearch.username: "elastic"
elasticsearch.password: "changeme"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"
```

### UPDATE

I am on a MAC and when I run a port Scan, here is the result
Port Scan a démarré…

Port Scanning host: 192.168.1.73

```
 Open TCP Port:     88          kerberos
 Open TCP Port:     445         microsoft-ds
 Open TCP Port:     3306        mysql
 Open TCP Port:     5433        pyrrho
 Open TCP Port:     33060
```

Port Scan a terminé…

### UPDATE

```
MBP-de-Admin:bin admin$ netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'
Active Internet connections (including servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)     rhiwat shiwat    pid   epid  state    options
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.54090        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   8126      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9202         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2419      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9202               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2419      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9302         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2419      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9302               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2419      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9201         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2278      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9201               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2278      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9301         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2278      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9301               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2278      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9200         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2141      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9200               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2141      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.9300         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2141      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.9300               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072   2141      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.49352        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    676      0 0x0100 0x00000026
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.50000        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    541      0 0x0100 0x00000106
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.49281        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    524      0 0x0000 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.4767         *.*                    LISTEN       65536  65536    513      0 0x0080 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.2432               *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    534      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.2432         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    534      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.5942         *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    116      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.5433                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    122      0 0x0000 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  *.5433                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    122      0 0x0000 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    160      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    160      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    165      0 0x0100 0x00000006
tcp46      0      0  *.33060                *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072    165      0 0x0000 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.59845        *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072      1      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  ::1.59845              *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072      1      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp4       0      0  *.445                  *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072      1      0 0x0180 0x00000006
tcp6       0      0  *.445                  *.*                    LISTEN      131072 131072      1      0 0x0180 0x00000006
```

Comment: Can you telnet port 9200 of Elasticsearch host on Kibana server?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by telnet host on Kibana server ? I am at the moment trying to start Kibana and it fails. I have no server

Comment: Can your Kibana instance see Elasticsearch 9200 port? what do you mean I have no server?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand what you say. I have installed Kibana but failed to start it. So can you detail what you mean ? For the moment due to start failing I have no instance of Kibana

Comment: OK, you are working on your local, execute `netstat -tulnp` and add the response to question body, I want to know what ports is open.

Comment: Thanks, netstat -tulnp didn't work so I run netstat -anvp tcp | awk 'NR<3 || /LISTEN/'

Comment: ok so you have 3 Elasticsearch instances, try 127.0.0.1:9200 in kibana.yml for elasticsearch-hosts and 0.0.0.0 for server.host

Comment: GREAT, many thanks, it works. By the way how can you say there are 3 instance of elasticsearch instances running. I can see only 2 lines corresponding to 9200 port. And why I must put 0.0.0.0 for server.host. What does it mean ?

Comment: I saw 9200 9201 9202 ports are open and I suppose you are using a docker-compose to create a 3 node elasticsearch cluster, 0.0.0.0 means it can be usable outside of the local through network.